# Dividing line extends into caption of table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I cannot fix, nor work out why my table has a dividing line - {l| - extends above my table into the caption. Nor can I figure out why the \bottomrule only extends to the first column. I think these issues are related but cannot figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\hrule

    \centering 
    \caption{Daily Trade Statistics for Spot and Futures Market. Average measures displayed in 'All' and quintiles by Market Capitalisation in rows Q5-Q1 (Smallest to Largest).}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|ccc|ccc} \\ \hline
\hline
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Number of Trades} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Volume of Trades} \\

\cmidrule{1-4} \cmidrule{5-7}

    & Mean & Median & Std. Dev. & Mean & Median & Std. Dev. \\ \hline
    
Panel A: Spot & & & & & \\ \hline
All & 35,027 & 23,224 & 37,907 & 5,463,166 & 1,629,666 & 16,345,297\\
Q5 (Smallest) &22,429 &14,803 &27,814 & 6,000,618 &1,867,395 &14,977,300\\
Q4 &27,611 &19,662 &28,999 & 9,477,202 &1,707,493 &29,538,178\\
Q3 &25,550 &16,852 &29,595 & 3,098,663 &975,992 &5,614,307\\
Q2 &40,105 &29,168 &43,990 & 4,832,524 &1,424,984&12,591,574\\
Q1 (Largest) &60,337 &51,511 &42,789 & 3,926,218 &2,327,745 &4,948,369\\ \hline

Panel B: Futures & & & & & &\\ \hline
All & 3,221 & 2,038 &4,001 & 11,351,964 & 4,284,000 & 22,528,779\\ 
Q5 (Smallest) &1,854 &1,418 &1,955 & 10,772,701 &5,375,500 &19,492,113\\
Q4 &2,599 &1,778 &2,765 & 15,654,102 &4,758,000 &35,638,730\\
Q3 &2,726 &1,656 &2,889 & 9,274,756 &2,973,000 &15,273,786\\
Q2 &3,363 &2,146 &4,639 & 11,620,665 &3,285,600 &22,456,704\\
Q1 (Largest) &6,115 &4,120 &5,411 & 8,414,534 &5,176,000 &10,327,336\\ 
\hline
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\label{trade_stats1}
\end{table}
```

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: Remove the `\\ ` before the first `\hline`.

Comment: Please also keep in mind that horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package (such as `\cmidrule`) are intended to be used without vertical lines and thus are incompatible. (See the small white gaps around the intersections)

Comment: Why did you decide to use `tabularx` without any `X` type column here? A simple `tabular*` (probably in combination with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` would be sufficient to make sure your table is as wide as the textwidth while columns are spread equally.

Comment: Hi @leandriis,thank you. Removing \\ fixed that first issue. Yes, I will take out midrule also - no need for it. Tabularx is redundant too. I will try with tabular* instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to remove the vertical line, remove the `\\`  right before the first `\hline` command:

In addition to that, I suggest some more changes:

- Usage of `tabular*` in combination with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` instead of `tabularx` in order to make sure the table is as wide as the textwidth while equally spreading the columns.
- Use of `S` type columns from the `siunitx` package in order to improve the alignment of numbers in the table
- Removed all vertical lines and replaced `\hline` commands with the appropriate horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package. Added `(r)` and `(l)` to the `\cmidrule` commands in order to create a gap in the line between column 4 and 5.
- Added the `caption` package for improved spacing around the caption.
- Slighly indented the contents of the first column with respect to the "Panel ..." headers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-ignore={,}, 
         input-decimal-markers = {.}, 
         group-separator={,}, }
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering 
    \caption{Daily Trade Statistics for Spot and Futures Market. Average measures displayed in 'All' and quintiles by Market Capitalisation in rows Q5-Q1 (Smallest to Largest).}
    \label{trade_stats1}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\quad\extracolsep{\fill}}l 
                             *{3}{S[table-format=5]} 
                             S[table-format=8] 
                             S[table-format=7] 
                             S[table-format=8]}  
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Number of Trades} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Volume of Trades} \\

\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}

    & {Mean} & {Median} & {Std. Dev.} & {Mean} & {Median} & {Std. Dev.} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Panel A: Spot}  \\ 
\midrule
All & 35,027 & 23,224 & 37,907 & 5,463,166 & 1,629,666 & 16,345,297\\
Q5 (Smallest) &22,429 &14,803 &27,814 & 6,000,618 &1,867,395 &14,977,300\\
Q4 &27,611 &19,662 &28,999 & 9,477,202 &1,707,493 &29,538,178\\
Q3 &25,550 &16,852 &29,595 & 3,098,663 &975,992 &5,614,307\\
Q2 &40,105 &29,168 &43,990 & 4,832,524 &1,424,984&12,591,574\\
Q1 (Largest) &60,337 &51,511 &42,789 & 3,926,218 &2,327,745 &4,948,369\\

\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Panel B: Futures} \\ 
\midrule
All & 3,221 & 2,038 &4,001 & 11,351,964 & 4,284,000 & 22,528,779\\ 
Q5 (Smallest) &1,854 &1,418 &1,955 & 10,772,701 &5,375,500 &19,492,113\\
Q4 &2,599 &1,778 &2,765 & 15,654,102 &4,758,000 &35,638,730\\
Q3 &2,726 &1,656 &2,889 & 9,274,756 &2,973,000 &15,273,786\\
Q2 &3,363 &2,146 &4,639 & 11,620,665 &3,285,600 &22,456,704\\
Q1 (Largest) &6,115 &4,120 &5,411 & 8,414,534 &5,176,000 &10,327,336\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @leandriis - that is really helpful. Thank you for the explanation too.